# Error importing pydoop.hdfs in python CLI

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop

I'm trying to access an hdfs file using pydoop working on IBM BigInsights and using the libraries provided by BigInsights. When I issue `import hadoop.hdfs` the following import error occurs.

```
>>>import pydoop.hdfs
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
 from fs import hdfs, default_is_local
 File "pydoop/hdfs/fs.py", line 28, in <module>
 hdfs_ext = pydoop.import_version_specific_module("_hdfs")
 File "pydoop/__init__.py", line 114, in import_version_specific_module
 return import_module(complete_mod_name(name))
 File "/opt/python/dev/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in     import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _hdfs_2_2_0
```

Comment: you have `import hadoop.hdfs` in a question's body and `import pydoop.hdfs` in code.. just choose one. Also specify the way you installed required package

Comment: Sorry hadoop.hdfs is a typo in question body.